# Writing to ecx register causes "Access violation" in Windows 7

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, assembly

Hello and thank you very much for your help!

In my c++ code I have some embedded assembler code and at the line [mov ecx,1AF858h] an error message keeps popping up saying "Access violation". It works perfectly with Windows XP but unfortunately not with Windows 7.

I don’t understand what causes the problem and I would like to know what I need to do to fix it.

Kind Regards, David

Comment: It very much depends on where that is done. Please show some more code. Also, is your code compiled to a 32 bit target in both cases?

Comment: If it is Visual Studio the inline assembly is only available in 32 bit mode. Inside a class the ECX register often holds the `this` pointer. Changing that might have "interesting" effects.

Comment: Is it really `[mov ecx,1AF858h]` and not `mov ecx,[1AF858h]`? Because in case of the latter its just a standard access violation while reading from address 0x1AF858 and has nothing to do with ecx. But anyway post more code and/or context of the error.

Comment: Background: I’m trying to load assembler code into a byte array and then execute it. I have tested a few other things and it looks like windows 7 does not permit any code execution from dynamically allocated memory blocks. Is this correct? Is there any way to work around this problem?

Comment: You can test with `mov ecx, 1234h`, if that doesn't yield access violation _right there_, then it's an AV of `1AF858h`. In that case you'll need what the answer below says about `Virtual*Protect`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [VirtualProtect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)/[VirtualProtectEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366899%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to mark your byte array as executable or allocate it with [VirtualAlloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366887%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) using the correct [flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366786%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (probably `PAGE_READWRITE` when writing the code and then `PAGE_EXECUTE_READ`). Note that it will probably need to be done on a page basis.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!!! It works now. The code I am using: VirtualProtect(ptr, size, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &flOldProtect)